# Updated rows not expected values with JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, sql-update, database-schema

I've created several tables in a test database based on columns/rows in my main database.

```
test.websites.url = main.websites.url
test.category_main = main.websites.category1
test.category_01 = main.websites.category2
test.category_02 = main.websites.category3
etc...
```

> The test database columns already contain all the rows from the main
>   database, but I need to add the rows from the respective tables to the 
>   `category_to_website` table and create `foreign keys` because there is
>   currently no relation between them in the test database. That is why I have joined the 
>   main database in the query.

When trying to use the main table as a reference for updating the existing rows in the test database, some values are updated but they are not always correct. *I'm executing the query from the test database.*

### My query:

```
UPDATE category_to_website
LEFT JOIN main.websites
ON websites.url = main.websites.url
LEFT JOIN category_01
ON category_01.name = main.websites.category2
SET category_to_website.category_01_id = category_01.id
WHERE category_to_website.category_01_id = main.websites.category2
```

### My database schema:

[image]

I suspect that the issue is with the type of `JOIN`s I am doing, but I've tried `LEFT JOIN`, `JOIN`, and `INNER JOIN` and get the same results. I think that maybe I need a `SELECT` sub query or my `WHERE` clause is off?

**EDIT**
Based on the comments I was able to get this all sorted out. Here are the steps I took.
1. Merged the `category_*` tables into a `category` table.
2. Joined the `test.websites` table into the query.

```
UPDATE test.category_to_website
LEFT JOIN test.websites
ON test.websites.id = category_to_website.url_id
RIGHT JOIN main.websites
ON test.websites.url = main.websites.url
INNER JOIN test.category
ON test.category.name = main.websites.category1
SET category_to_website.category01_id = category.id
WHERE category_to_website.url_id = test.websites.id
```

Comment: It seems at the very least that you are trying to reference column `test.websites.url` without ever joining table `test.websites` into the query. That won't work; I'm guessing MySQL takes `websites.url = main.websites.url` to be `main.websites.url = main.websites.url` since that's the only `websites` table part of the query at that point. For an actual answer, I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TomasCreemers - I've added more information about the relation of the columns between the two databases. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Shouldn't `category_01.name = main.websites.category2` be `category_01.name = main.websites.category1` ?

Comment: I added it to my question, but actually `test.category_main = main.websites.category1` and `test.category_01 = main.websites.category2`. The column names don't exactly match up between them if that makes any sense.

Comment: @EternalHour: The remark remains: your `UPDATE` statement refers to three tables: `test.category_to_website`, `main.websites` and `test.category_01`. The join condition `websites.url = main.websites.url` seems odd.

Comment: I understand it's confusing, I've explained the best I can in the question.

Comment: You need to fix your design. You **should not** have `categoryN` column. You should have a category table, and a category lookup table.

Comment: @philipxy - Thanks for the explanation. I'm not quite sure, I'll have to try it. I just created a category table as suggested so the query is going to be a little different.

Comment: @TomasCreemers - You were absolutely correct about needing to join the `test.websites` into the query. Please post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @philipxy - Ok. I'm not knowledgeable about DBA stuff. I've created a category table, with a varchar names column and then an int id column. I then have the category_to_website lookup table which has an int website id column, and then several more int columns for the category id's. Is that a correct design?

Comment: Please always give your table definitions and example data whenever you post a query, that you have tested at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). Why not record what was wrong with your design & query in your "EDIT" for future understanding (since comments are not permanent). Maybe even post an answer to your question yourself & when (maybe eventually) it is correct you can even accept it.

Comment: So what you're saying then, is that the category_to_website table should only have primary key, website id, and category id (which are both foreign keys)?

Comment: Yes! And if {website_id,category_id} is UNIQUE NOT NULL (is a candidate key)(one of which can be declared via PRIMARY KEY) then do you really need an id column? (Although some ORMs require one-column PKs or auto-generated PKs.) And do the same in your main tables. (See my answer below.) (PS use @ to notify one person of many.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE category_to_website
JOIN websites
ON websites.id = category_to_website.url_id
JOIN main.websites
ON websites.url = main.websites.url
JOIN category
ON category.name = main.websites.category1
SET category_to_website.category01_id = category.id
```

`SET`s are done to rows that participate in the `JOIN`s. But if you `LEFT JOIN` to `category_to_website` then all its rows participate so then you must restrict them in a WHERE the way you *already did* in the ON.

*Thank goodness* you have started to relationalize that horrible schema. Keep going: replace all multiple `categery_` columns in each table by just one `category` column for id or name. And if you *named* them `category_id` and `category_name` their nature would be clear. (Maybe post your next version as a new question.)